# Call AS400 RPG from SQL Server returning parameter

Tags: sql-server, db2, linked-server, db2-400, clp

In my SQL Server instance I have a linked server to AS400.

I want to exec a CLP program that takes 2 parameters, a `numeric(8,0)` as input and an `alphanumeric(3)` as output.

These are SQL commands that I use to do it:

```
DECLARE @Ret varchar(3)
DECLARE @Date varchar(8)
SET @Date = '20200721'
SET @Ret = '   '

EXEC ('CALL IASP01.WUTL.WUTL46(''' + @Date + ''', ''?'')', @Ret) AT AS400 

SELECT @Ret
```

The command is executed without errors, but no results are returned.

The second parameter is a `varchar(3)` param because AS400 expects an alphanumeric parameter to return result but it's always empty.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

I also tried to create a simple CLP that accepts only 1 parameter and modifies its value.
Following is the simple CLP code:

```
PGM        PARM(&DATA)                                  
            DCL        VAR(&DATA) TYPE(*DEC) LEN(8 0)                
            CHGVAR     VAR(&DATA) VALUE(20200722)                                                                       
            ENDPGM
```

It's a very simple program that accepts a numeric(8,0) parameter and modifies it's value.

And here's the Sql Server code that I use to execute DB2 RPG:

declare @P1 numeric(8, 0)
select @P1 = 00000000

exec ('CALL .<RPG_Name>(''?'')', @P1 OUTPUT) AT AS400
select @P1

The execution succeeded without errors.
After this call, the @P1 variable contains the initial value and not the modified value, so I'm not able to get the "return" value in Sql Server after this call.
How can I do it?

Or how can I return a value from CLP to Sql Server?

Thanks

Comment: Show us the definition of the RPG program. Particularly the `*ENTRY PLIST` and the definition of the parameters on it.

Comment: Hi @jmarkmurphy, The program I call is a CLP program and not an RPG...sorry. I updated my initial question with another example and the simple CLP code. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what does your stored procedure definition look like? The one on IBM i.

Comment: On IBM I've only the CLP described above and it's directly called by a Sql Server query. The above code is the complete CLP code. Do you need something more?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a stored procedure definition on DB2.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a stored procedure definition in DB2. I am surprised it works at all without that, but maybe DB2 is smart enough to call the program on a call with default parameter definitions. Unfortunately the default parameter definitions are Input only.

You can find documentation in the [Knowledge Base](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzcrtpef.htm). But it goes something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SIMPLE_CLP
  (INOUT DATA DECIMAL(8, 0))
  LANGUAGE CL
  PARAMETER STYLE GENERAL
  DETERMINISTIC
  NO SQL
  EXTERNAL NAME 'SIMPLE_CLP';
```

Then you should be able to use INOUT parameters.